# How to Write checkbox with foreach?

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, .net-core

I have a List of Menus which has a property of IsChecked.

I wrote the checkbox list and set the asp-for

```
@foreach (var a in Model.Menus.FindAll(x => x.Pid == item.ID))
                                        {
                                            <div class="form-check">
                                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" asp-for="@a.IsChecked" />
                                                <label for="checkbox1" class="form-check-label">@a.Name</label>
                                            </div>
                                        }
```

But in the OnPostAsync function the Menus is null. I have already declared  the Menus :`public List<Model.Menus>Menus{get;set;}`
and the OnPostAsync is activated.
How could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to use the `asp-for` tag helper with your collection:

```
@{ 
    var index = 0;
    // Required or the index won't match
    Model.Menus = Model.Menus.FindAll(x => x.Pid == item.ID).ToList();
}
@foreach (var a in Model.Menus)
{
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Menus[index].IsChecked" />
        <label asp-for="@Model.Menus[index].IsChecked" class="form-check-label">@a.Name</label>
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Menus[index].Id" />
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Menus[index].Name" />
    </div>
    index++;
}
```